# conda nbconvert PermissionError: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/html/full.tpl' (mac catalina)

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, nbconvert

I just did a fresh command line install of Anaconda on Mac Catalina

conda 4.7.12
I can run conda and jupyter lab from the command line. 
but when I try to run jupyter nbconvert test.ipynb I get a permission error

```
File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 340, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 510, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 481, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 410, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 179, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 197, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/html.py", line 95, in from_notebook_node
    return super(HTMLExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 322, in from_notebook_node
    output = self.template.render(nb=nb_copy, resources=resources)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 114, in template
    self._template_cached = self._load_template()
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 293, in _load_template
    return self.environment.get_template(template_file)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 405, in load
    return loader.load(environment, name, globals)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 78, in get_source
    return self.loader.get_source(environment, template)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 171, in get_source
    f = open_if_exists(filename)
  File "/Users/admin/Anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 154, in open_if_exists
    return open(filename, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/html/full.tpl'
```

I notice also that when I run base) admin@JonSchuPretina3 ~ %

```
ls -l /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert
```

I get

```
ls: nbconvert: Permission denied
```

I understand users and groups just enough to provide the following perhaps-relevant information

```
ls -l /usr/local/share/jupyter/ 
rwxr-xr-x  3 jonschull-MBPR  wheel   96 Jan 24  2018 kernels
drwxr-x--x  3 jonschull-MBPR  wheel   96 Nov 17 13:07 nbconvert
drwxr-xr-x  4 jonschull-MBPR  wheel  128 Apr  7  2019 nbextensions

groups
~ % groups
staff everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _appstore _lpoperator _developer _analyticsusers com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.access_remote_ae com.apple.sharepoint.group.4
```